# Display TIF image in a window using Win32

Tags: winapi, tiff

I'm new in programming a Win32 program. I want to display a tif image in the window, but I only found ways to display bitmap image. Does anyone got idea about how to display a tif image? Thanks.

Comment: Try using GDI+. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882579.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use `Gdiplus::Bitmap` class to load TIFF image. Then, get `HBITMAP` from it by calling `GetHBITMAP`.